# How to get rrdcached configured for collectd on CentOS 6.4?

Tags: centos, collectd

I am trying to build collectd 5.2 on CentOS 6.4. I am unable to configure it with rrdcached.

I have installd rrdtool-devel and related packages.

Googling did not reveal anything which works.

Any hints?

Comment: What is the output of the configure script?

Comment: Nothing interesting...   It simply lists rrdcached module as not available  :::      rrdcached . . . . . . no      rrdtool . . . . . . . yes